# android studio recyclerView with firestore

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have orders collection in firestore:
[image]

And I have Sellers collection and inside Sellers collection have another Fruits collection :
[image]

I want to get data in orders collection only orders collection fruit_ID equals Sellers/Fruits collection Document ID and add into recyclerview

Is it possible?

Activity class:

```
package com.example.freshbucket.Seller;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.freshbucket.Adapter.OrdersSellerRecylerAdapter;
import com.example.freshbucket.Model.PlaceOrder;
import com.example.freshbucket.R;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

import static android.support.constraint.Constraints.TAG;

public class SellerGetOrdersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String fid, pro;

   private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference orders = db.collection("Orders");
    private CollectionReference sellers = db.collection("Sellers/"+user_id+"/Fruits");

    private OrdersSellerRecylerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seller_get_orders);

        setupRecyclerView();

    }

    private void setupRecyclerView()
    {

        Query query =orders.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).whereEqualTo("fruit_ID",fid);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<PlaceOrder> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<PlaceOrder>().setQuery(query, PlaceOrder.class).build();

        adapter = new OrdersSellerRecylerAdapter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.ordersReView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //swipe delete
        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT| ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder1) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
                adapter.deleteItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();



       sellers.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {



                if (e != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error:" + e.getMessage());
                } else {

                    for (DocumentSnapshot doc :queryDocumentSnapshots){

                        fid = doc.getId();

                       // pro = doc.getString("province");
                       // fid = doc.getString("fruit_ID");
                        Toast.makeText(SellerGetOrdersActivity.this, "Register error:" +fid , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                               }



                }

            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
  }
```

Adapter:

```
    package com.example.freshbucket.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.freshbucket.Model.PlaceOrder;
import com.example.freshbucket.R;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;

public class OrdersSellerRecylerAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<PlaceOrder, OrdersSellerRecylerAdapter.OrdersSellerHolder> {

    Context context;


    public OrdersSellerRecylerAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<PlaceOrder> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final OrdersSellerHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final PlaceOrder model) {

       holder.txtfruitname.setText(model.getName());
       holder.txtqun.setText(model.getQun());
       holder.txtcusname.setText(model.getCustomer_Name());
        holder.txtaddress1.setText(model.getAddressLine1());
        holder.txtaddress2.setText(model.getAddressLine2());
        holder.txtcity.setText(model.getCity());


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public OrdersSellerHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.order_list_item_seller,viewGroup, false);
        context = viewGroup.getContext();


        return new OrdersSellerHolder(v);
    }


    class OrdersSellerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

       TextView txtfruitname, txtqun, txtcusname, txtaddress1, txtaddress2, txtcity;
       EditText tctBprice;


        public OrdersSellerHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtfruitname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fruitnametext);
            txtqun = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fruitquntext);
            txtcusname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cusnametext);
            txtaddress1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addres1text);
            txtaddress2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addres2text);
            txtcity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.citytext);


        }


    }

    public void deleteItem(int position) {
        getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
    }




}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get data in orders collection only orders collection
>   fruit_ID

OK, you want to get fruit_ID?

[image]

> equals Sellers/Fruits collection Document ID and add into recyclerview

and you want to get fruit_ID, which equals with Sellers/Fruits ?

like `if (fruit_ID.equals(sellerFruits_ID) {// get fruit_ID}`

[image]

I will try to answer it.

PROBLEM

**1. you as a seller and have your `seller uid` in your `Sellers` collection  and want to get `V4x1Dh..`**

**2. You have `buyer uid` in your `Orders` collection and want to get `83Fmf..`**

**3. You want to get Banana in Sellers/Fruits, which the Banana as id.**

**Lastly, you want to load datas of `Sellers/Fruits` into `recyclerView` because**

> you want to get data in orders collection only orders collection
>   fruit_ID

ANSWER

Answer number one: Please retrieve the Sellers `ids` and get `V4x1Dh` *based `ViewHolder position` that I will explain later.*

Answer number two: Please retrieve the Orders `ids` and get `83Fmf` *based `ViewHolder position` that I will explain later.*

Answer number two: Please retrieve the Sellers Fruits `ids` let's say `sellerFruit_ID` and get `Banana` *based `ViewHolder position` that I will explain later.* NOTE: Since Banana in document it will be id.

DETAILS:

**Retrieving the Sellers `ids` and get `V4x1Dh`:**

```
    firebaseFirestore
     .collection("Sellers")
     .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>(){
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e){

            for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){

                if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){

                    // RETRIEVING Orders id
                    String orders_ID = doc.getDocument().getId();
                    YourContentOrdersHere contentOrders = doc.getDocument().toObject(YourContentOrdersHere.class).withId(orders_ID);

                    // RETRIEVING Sellers id
                    String sellers_ID = doc.getDocument().getId();
                    YourContentSellersHere contentSellers = doc.getDocument().toObject(YourContentSellersHere.class).withId(sellers_ID);

                    contentListOrders.add(contentOrders);   //example: List<YourContentOrdersHere> contentList                
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // before of course, you add this in onCreate adapterOrders = new YourAdapterOrders(contentListOrders);

                    contentListSellers.add(contents);   //example: List<YourContentSellersHere> contentList                
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // before of course, you add this in onCreate adapterSellers = new YourAdapterSellers(contentListSellers);
                }
            }


        }
    });
```

make sure your content class extends the ids

```
public class YourContentOrdersHere extends OrdersId {

// make your constructor here of course
// make your getter to get id

}
```

and make **OrdersId.class**

```
public class OrdersId{


    @Exclude
    public String OrdersId;

    public <T extends OrdersId> T withId(@NonNull final String id) {

        this.OrdersId = id;
        return (T) this;
    }
}
```

and last one , from your adapter class retrieving OrdersId. As Example:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        // GET YOUR `Sellers` id based position and getSellerId() from getter of your content class
        String sellers_ID = contentListSeller.get(position).getSellerId(); // don't forget List<YourContentSellers> contentList = new ArrayList<>();
        firebaseFirestore
           .collection("Sellers")
           .document(sellers_ID)
           .collection("Fruits")
           .document("Banana")


// STORE 'LIKE TAP' USING LIKE BUTTON
        holder.likeHome.seOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                /* RETRIEVING VALUE UNDER currentUserId */
                firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + postId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task){

                        if (!task.getResult().exists()) {

                            /* STORE NEW VALUE */
                            Map<String, Object> likesMap = new HashMap<>();
                            likesMap.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp);
                            firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + postId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).set(likesMap);
                        } else {
                            // retrieve like timestamp
                            String whenToLike = task.getResult().getString("timestamp");
                            holder.setWhenToLike(whenToLike);

                            /* DELETE VALUE */
                            firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts/" + postId + "/Likes").document(currentUserId).delete();
                        }
                    }
                });                
            }
        });


}
```

Comment: It looks like you got yourself into a pickle in this answer. There are several things you planned to explain at another time, and then you forgot to come back to explain them. If you don't have time to post an answer, it is best to save it another time until you can post it fully. Remember that voters generally respond to the state of the post when they see it, and they generally do not come back to adjust their vote.

Comment: Would you edit the material that says you will explain later?